# アカウントの不正利用を知る方策はありますか？

Tags: サポート

Yahoo Japan などでは「ログイン履歴」を見ることができます。
オイラが普段使っていない ISP からのログイン履歴があったら
第三者によるアカウントの不正利用が疑われるわけですが SO にも類似の機能はあるのでしょうか？

いや SO/SE はお金が絡むサービスではないのでどうでもよいっちゃどうでもよいのですが。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

不正アクセスを自動的に監視する方法はあります。悪用に使われないように、詳細は公開していません。

もし不正アクセスがあると思うと[問い合わせ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)してくれたら調べることができます。

Comment: エキスパートとしては自己管理のほうが望ましかったりしますが、一般ユーザーとしてはシステム上、自動監視のほうが手間も無くて楽なのでしょうね。今回この質問に至った経緯は identicon がオイラの知らないところで勝手に変わっていたためなわけですが、不具合 (SO 側か Gravatar 側かは確定していませんが) ということなのでこれ以上の追求は不要と考えます。

Comment: @774RR 当サイトのOpenIdを利用しているなら、[ここで](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user)過去のアクセスを調べることができますが、Google等のログインを利用してたらできません。

Comment: SE OPENID のページに直接ログインすると、そのログイン元としては社内の web proxy server のアドレスが見えました。でも ja.stackoverflow のログイン元は謎の `10.x.y.z` class A private address となっておりました。なんなんでしょうね？

Comment: @774RR StackExchangeからのメールのReceivedヘッダでも同様のアドレスが確認できます。各サイトにログインした際にSEの社内ネットワーク内でStackAuthにログイン処理が走って、その際のAppサーバーのアドレスなんじゃないかなーと推測してます。

Comment: うーん。だとするとこの SE OPENID ログイン履歴は不正アクセス確認には使えませんね・・・だれがどこからログインしても SE 社内ネットワークの値になっちゃうわけですから。